# An extra page appears when compiling

Tags: page-breaking

I'm having an "strange" problem when compiling a document made of different chapters. I use this code in the main file:

```
\include{Capitulos/01Introduccion}
\include{Capitulos/02Metodologia}
\include{Capitulos/03ClimatologiaSST}
\include{Capitulos/04Modelizacion}
\include{Capitulos/05Conclusiones}
```

Then when compiling an extra page with just an F appears after chapter 3. I thought it was because the chapter ended with a long table but when table is removed the problem also appears. Then I removed chapters 4 and 5, chapter 3 is then just before the appendix, and then the page with just an F disappears.

Any hint will be appreciated.

[image: Image showing extra page with only 'F']

**EDIT**

main `aux`-file:

```
\relax 
\catcode`"\active
\catcode`<\active
\catcode`>\active
\@nameuse{es@quoting}
\catcode`'\active
\providecommand\HyperFirstAtBeginDocument{\AtBeginDocument}
\HyperFirstAtBeginDocument{\ifx\hyper@anchor\@undefined
\global\let\oldcontentsline\contentsline
\gdef\contentsline#1#2#3#4{\oldcontentsline{#1}{#2}{#3}}
\global\let\oldnewlabel\newlabel
\gdef\newlabel#1#2{\newlabelxx{#1}#2}
\gdef\newlabelxx#1#2#3#4#5#6{\oldnewlabel{#1}{{#2}{#3}}}
\AtEndDocument{\ifx\hyper@anchor\@undefined
\let\contentsline\oldcontentsline
\let\newlabel\oldnewlabel
\fi}
\fi}
\global\let\hyper@last\relax 
\gdef\HyperFirstAtBeginDocument#1{#1}
\providecommand\HyField@AuxAddToFields[1]{}
\@input{Cascaras/cover.aux}
\select@language{spanish}
\@writefile{toc}{\select@language{spanish}}
\@writefile{lof}{\select@language{spanish}}
\@writefile{lot}{\select@language{spanish}}
\@input{Cascaras/dedicatoria.aux}
\@input{Cascaras/agradecimientos.aux}
\@input{TeXiS/TeXiS_toc.aux}
\@input{Capitulos/01Introduccion.aux}
\@input{Capitulos/02Metodologia.aux}
\@input{Capitulos/03ClimatologiaSST.aux}
\@input{Capitulos/05Modelizacion.aux}
\@input{Capitulos/06Conclusiones.aux}
\@input{Apendices/01Rams.aux}
\@input{Apendices/02MapasSinopticos.aux}
\@input{Apendices/03MapasSST.aux}
\@input{Cascaras/bibliografia.aux}
\@input{Cascaras/fin.aux}
```

`aux`-file of chapter 3

```
\relax 
\citation{Bethoux1999}
\citation{Vargas2010}
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {chapter}{\numberline {3}Climatolog\IeC {\'\i }a de la temperatura superficial del mar}{33}{chapter.3}}
\@writefile{lof}{\addvspace {10\p@ }}
\@writefile{lot}{\addvspace {10\p@ }}
\newlabel{cap3}{{3}{33}{Climatología de la \tsm \relax }{chapter.3}{}}
\newlabel{cap:climatologia}{{3}{33}{Climatología de la \tsm \relax }{chapter.3}{}}
\citation{Millan1995,Pastor2001,Estrela2003,Lebeaupin2006}
\citation{Nykjaer2009}
\citation{Rixen2005,Salat2002,Santoleri1994}
\citation{Ortenzio2000}
\citation{Marullo2007}
\citation{Kilpatrick2001}
\citation{Gentemann2003}
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {section}{\numberline {3.1}Datos de temperatura superficial del mar{} y metodolog\IeC {\'\i }a}{35}{section.3.1}}
\newlabel{cap3:sec:datosSST}{{3.1}{35}{Datos de \tsm {} y metodología\relax }{section.3.1}{}}
\citation{Kaufman1990}
\citation{R2010}
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {section}{\numberline {3.2}An\'alisis de la temperatura superficial del mar}{36}{section.3.2}}
\newlabel{cap3:sec:analisisSST}{{3.2}{36}{Análisis de la \tsm \relax }{section.3.2}{}}
\@writefile{lof}{\contentsline {figure}{\numberline {3.1}{\ignorespaces Media mensual de la temperatura superficial del mar{}}}{37}{figure.caption.8}}
\newlabel{fig:globalSSTmean}{{3.1}{37}{Media mensual de la \tsm {}\relax }{figure.caption.8}{}}
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {subsection}{\numberline {3.2.1}Climatolog\IeC {\'\i }a}{38}{subsection.3.2.1}}
\newlabel{cap3:sec:temporalSST}{{3.2.1}{38}{Climatología\relax }{subsection.3.2.1}{}}
\citation{R2010}
\@writefile{lof}{\contentsline {figure}{\numberline {3.2}{\ignorespaces Ciclo anual de la temperatura superficial del mar{}}}{39}{figure.caption.9}}
\newlabel{fig:annualSST}{{3.2}{39}{Ciclo anual de la \tsm {}\relax }{figure.caption.9}{}}
\@writefile{lof}{\contentsline {figure}{\numberline {3.3}{\ignorespaces Temperatura superficial del mar media mensual Agosto 2003}}{39}{figure.caption.10}}
\newlabel{fig:SST200308}{{3.3}{39}{Temperatura superficial del mar media mensual Agosto 2003\relax }{figure.caption.10}{}}
\@writefile{lof}{\contentsline {figure}{\numberline {3.4}{\ignorespaces Anomal\IeC {\'\i }a de temperatura superficial del mar media mensual Agosto 2003}}{40}{figure.caption.11}}
\newlabel{fig:SSTanom200308}{{3.4}{40}{Anomalía de temperatura superficial del mar media mensual Agosto 2003\relax }{figure.caption.11}{}}
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {subsection}{\numberline {3.2.2}Distribuci\'on espacial}{40}{subsection.3.2.2}}
\newlabel{cap3:sec:espacialSST}{{3.2.2}{40}{Distribución espacial\relax }{subsection.3.2.2}{}}
\@writefile{lof}{\contentsline {figure}{\numberline {3.5}{\ignorespaces Temperatura superficial del mar media mensual y cl\'ustering verano-invierno}}{41}{figure.caption.12}}
\newlabel{fig:SSTclustering}{{3.5}{41}{Temperatura superficial del mar media mensual y clústering verano-invierno\relax }{figure.caption.12}{}}
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {subsection}{\numberline {3.2.3}Conclusi\'on - Resumen}{42}{subsection.3.2.3}}
\@writefile{lot}{\contentsline {table}{\numberline {3.1}{\ignorespaces TSM media}}{44}{table.caption.13}}
\newlabel{cap3:tab:tsmmedia}{{3.1}{44}{TSM media\relax }{table.caption.13}{}}
\@setckpt{Capitulos/03ClimatologiaSST}{
\setcounter{page}{45}
\setcounter{equation}{1}
\setcounter{enumi}{4}
\setcounter{enumii}{0}
\setcounter{enumiii}{0}
\setcounter{enumiv}{0}
\setcounter{footnote}{1}
\setcounter{mpfootnote}{0}
\setcounter{part}{0}
\setcounter{chapter}{3}
\setcounter{section}{2}
\setcounter{subsection}{3}
\setcounter{subsubsection}{0}
\setcounter{paragraph}{0}
\setcounter{subparagraph}{0}
\setcounter{figure}{5}
\setcounter{table}{1}
\setcounter{parentequation}{0}
\setcounter{LT@tables}{0}
\setcounter{LT@chunks}{0}
\setcounter{float@type}{8}
\setcounter{NAT@ctr}{0}
\setcounter{Item}{9}
\setcounter{Hfootnote}{1}
\setcounter{bookmark@seq@number}{29}
\setcounter{ContinuedFloat}{0}
\setcounter{KVtest}{0}
\setcounter{subfigure}{0}
\setcounter{subfigure@save}{2}
\setcounter{lofdepth}{1}
\setcounter{subtable}{0}
\setcounter{subtable@save}{0}
\setcounter{lotdepth}{1}
\setcounter{lstnumber}{1}
\setcounter{section@level}{0}
\setcounter{lstlisting}{0}
}
```

Comment: the question is tagged longtable but doesn't appear to be table related. Where is the F? page head?, page body? Is there anything labelling in alphabetic sequence A b C... F in your document, any other clue you might want to share:-)

Comment: Hi and thanks for answering. I tagged as longtable as I thought it might come from the long table at the end of the chapter. You can see a screenshot at http://dl.dropbox.com/u/244041/Captura.PNG There is not any alphabetic labelling in the document.

Comment: I added your image inline thanks. Really there is not much we can say. You will need to progressively remove bits of your document while keeping the F until the only thing left, then the bit of the document that is left is the cause....

Comment: Try to continuously remove text before the 'F' page and check if it disappears. Also check for any fancy trailing Unicode characters, which could be hard to see. Without seeing the full code it isn't really possible to help you further.

Comment: Another thing: Check the `.aux` files for anything which could produce an 'F'. These files are read in after the last page have been flushed and can add new material, which then would appear on an extra page. The same is true for `\AtEndDocument{..}`.

Comment: Thanks Martin, I'm not so experienced with LaTeX so it is the first.aux I look at. You can find it at http://dl.dropbox.com/u/244041/tesis.aux

Comment: And the aux file for chapter 3, the one with the F: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/244041/03ClimatologiaSST.aux

Comment: @pacomet: Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates your problem. We need it!

Comment: Note that the chapter change (in conjunction with a page break) is not caused by the `\include` command, but by the `\chapter` inside it. So, if the file `Capitulos/04Modelizacion.tex` contains anything (say, an `F`) *before* the `\chapter`, this will cause exactly the effect you're seeing.

Comment: @StephanLehmke: Is this the answer ;-)

Comment: @MarcoDaniel Only pacomet will be able to say...

Comment: @StephanLehmke Thank you very much, you were right. An extra F before the \chapter command. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Stephan Lehmke said the problem was not in the chapter where the F appeared but in the following one which had the extra character (F) before the \chapter command.

Thanks again to Stephan and the other users comments.